# Spring boot 2.4.5 Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade the Spring boot version from `2.3.10.RELEASE` to `2.4.5`. But whenever I try to run this command: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local`, it is throwing below exception:

```
17:24:15.538 [restartedMain] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9522e3aa] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
17:24:15.546 [restartedMain] WARN  org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
17:24:15.555 [restartedMain] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-10 17:24:15,571 restartedMain INFO sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. ReflectionUtil.getCallerClass will be much slower due to this. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.reflect.Reflection
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

Other details:

- Java version: 11

Is there anything that I need to configure? Thanks in advance

Comment: That isn't the problem as that is an INFO message not the error. The actual error is a couple of lines up, and it seems you are mixing different versions of modules from Spring or Spring Boot.

Comment: Any idea which modules might be causing this issue?

Comment: Without seeing your dependencies this is impossible to tell.

Comment: Okay I will post Pom.XML